# How can i get distinct values from my mongodb

Tags: mongodb, next.js, frontend

So, in my application i want to get all the values of the property "Alimento"

```
    {
    "foods": [
        {
            "_id": "6318c906904b22a684659009",
            "Alimento": "Papinha Infantil de Ameixa NESTLÉ",
            "CategoriaDeAlimentos": "Alimento Infantil",
            "TabelaNutricional": [
                {
                    "Calorias": 0.83,
                    "Carboidratos": 0.19,
                    "Proteína": 0,
                    "Gorduta Total:": 0.02,
                    "Sódio": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "6318c906904b22a68465900a",
            "Alimento": "Papinha Infantil de Banana NESTLÉ",
            "CategoriaDeAlimentos": "Alimento Infantil",
            "TabelaNutricional": [
                {
                    "Calorias": 0.67,
                    "Carboidratos": 0.16,
                    "Proteína": 0,
                    "Gorduta Total:": 0,
                    "Sódio": 0
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get the values using the distinct method, as i have used many times before in react with help of mongoose (now im using nextjs with mongodb), but im getting an error.

```js
    const handler = async (req, res) => {
      const { db } = await databaseConnection();
    
      try {
        const foodCaterogies = await db.collection('foods').find({}).distinct().toArray();
    
        res.status(200).json({ foods: foodCaterogies });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
```

The error:

```js
        db.collection(...).find(...).distinct is not a function
```

Comment: you want the dinstinct values inside the array foods(distinct in 1 doc)? or distinct values in all the collection?

Comment: distinct vallues in the collection Alimento

Comment: mongodb has collections that each contains documents, your collection is called Alimento, and it has documents like the one you sended, and you want the distinct values in all the collection? fix your question to be more clear if you can. You say that your collection is called alimento, and you do  db.collection('foods'). and foods appear to be an array, its comfusing

Comment: start with the collection,show us 1-2 documents, what you want to do, and the expected ouput so we know

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake. The collection is called foods, and i want all the values of the field Alimento.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by a query parameter. Hope it will help you:

```
app.get('/myFood', async(req, res) =>{
  const Alimento = req.query.Alimento;
  const query = {Alimento: Alimento};
  const foodAlimento = await foodCollection(YourCollectionName of DB).find(query).toArray();
  console.log(foodAlimento);
  res.send(foodAlimento);
})
```